# which http status codes should I use for command failure in remote machine

Tags: java, http, playframework

I've an API which will take remote machine credentials & commands in JSON, it will execute commands in remote machine by log in with those credentials.

While executing those commands I'm getting exceptions like Auth Failure, connection refused, I should respond to User with above messages.

Questions :

Which Http status code I should use to respond user when above exceptions happened?

How to handle those scenarios?

Comment: 500. It isn't the HTTP client's business what failed unless it was his own request, his own authentication, etc., to the server that is reporting the error. Don't leak information.

Comment: Thanks for your response @EJP       I did not understand, Can you please a bit more clear?   "It isn't the HTTP client's business what failed unless it was his own request, his own authentication,"

Comment: See [HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) for an overview. 401 UNAUTHORIZED might be helpful. Just a 500 would not.

Comment: If the client's authentication to your server failed, it's a 401. If your server's authentication to the remote host fails, it's none of the clients business, it's a 500.

Answer (score 1):

it is an internal server error hence I suggest to use one of the 500 family, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for the list of the http status codes.

Usually an http 500 is enought, it's up to you to show or not detailed error information